# Pandas Dateoffset behaviour not consistent

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add months to a timestamp object and do not understand the following behaviour:

```
import pandas as pd

t1 = pd.Timestamp('2020-05-29')+4*pd.DateOffset(months=3)
t2 = pd.Timestamp('2020-05-29')+2*pd.DateOffset(months=6)
```

I would think that t1 and t2 should be equal (12 months in both cases) but t1 is Timestamp('2021-05-28 00:00:00') and t2 is Timestamp('2021-05-29 00:00:00')

Is this a bug? the correct answer should be t2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding DateOffsets expressed in months is a tricky issue.
Actually expression like `pd.Timestamp('2020-05-29') + 4 * pd.DateOffset(months=3)`
is executed under the hood by adding this offset 4 times.

Run such a code:

```
tt = pd.Timestamp('2020-05-29')
for i in range(4):
    tt += pd.DateOffset(months=3)
    print(f'{i}: {tt}')
```

and you will get:

```
0: 2020-08-29 00:00:00
1: 2020-11-29 00:00:00
2: 2021-02-28 00:00:00
3: 2021-05-28 00:00:00
```

Note that when you add 3 months to *2020-11-29* the result is **28-th**
day of February, since Feruary in *2021* has only 28 days.

The next addition, starting from this date, yields *2021-05-28* (day is
also *28*).

But when you add DateOffset of **6** months, the situation is as you
executed:

```
tt = pd.Timestamp('2020-05-29')
for i in range(2):
    tt += pd.DateOffset(months=6)
    print(f'{i}: {tt}')
```

the result is:

```
0: 2020-11-29 00:00:00
1: 2021-05-29 00:00:00
```

Just as intended, since no "stop" on the end of February occurred.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way in pandas to force the output in both cases to be the same? i.e. t0-pd.DateOffset(months=3), t0-pd.DateOffset(months=2*3), t0-pd.DateOffset(months=3*3),  etc. i.e. multiply the offset first and then move the date?

Comment: When the code is like "+ 4 * pd.DateOffset(months=3)", such cases are
probably unavoidable. Attempt to add *pd.DateOffset(months=12)* or just
*pd.DateOffset(year=1)* without preceding multiplier.